# LogCatError "setDataSource: outside path in JNI is ?x@" when playing music with mediaplayer

Tags: android

I have a strange problem when playing music files with the mediaplayer.

The playback starts without any problems and everything works fine. The app doesn't crash. But everytime I select a song I get the following LogCatError:

> 11-18 16:26:19.800: E/MediaPlayer(11367): setDataSource JAVA path
>
> 11-18 16:26:19.800: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(11367): setDataSource: outside
>   path in JNI is ?x@
>
> 11-18 16:26:19.855: E/MediaPlayer(11367): In prepareAsync
>
> 11-18 16:26:20.005: W/MediaPlayer(11367): info/warning (1, 44)

I don't download the files from the internet, I just play the songs stored on the device.

If nobody could give me a solution, it would be nice if anybody could explain the error to me.

Comment: Same error here, but playing a live http streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try catch around you mediaplayer datasource, like this:

```
try {
                mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), ringtoneUri);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

You have to catch all Exceptions.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try using ES File Explorer or something similar to check the properties/permissions of the file you want to play and try making it world readable

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,  the file was in "*.wmv" format, then i converted file to mp3 and tried same code and it worked, please find code below

```
try {
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource("http://Server.com/XXXX.mp3");
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```